# React-router 2.0: passing username from login to children

Tags: reactjs, react-router

*Please don't mark this as duplicate if you find something pointing to react-router 1.x. The answers I've read on StackOverflow regarding this issue use deprecated syntax.*

I'm trying to set up an app where on the base ("/") path, there is a very simple login page, and after logging in, the user's username is passed down via props to all the children (it will end up being used in all subsequent API calls as a parameter).

The problem is that react-router doesn't seem to recognize props added to the `<Route>` tags other than `component`, `route`, etc.

Routes:

```
render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Login} />
      <Route path="/feed" component={Feed} />
      <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('react-content'));
```

App.js:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {username: ''};
  },
  updateUser: function(name) {
    this.setState({username: name});
  },
  render: function() {
    return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, 
      {username: this.state.username, assignUser: this.updateUser}
      );
  }
});
```

Login.js:

```
var Login = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {user: this.props.username};
  },
  userLogin: function(value) {
    setTimeout(this.props.assignUser(value), 0);
    this.context.router.push('/feed');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="loginBody">
        <div className="formDiv">
          <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={this.userLogin(value)}>
            <select value="user1">
              <option value="user1">User 1</option>
              <option value="user2">User 2</option>
              <option value="user3">User 3</option>
              <option value="user4">User 4</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
});
```

I'm also not sure how `username` would get passed down to the `<Feed>` and `<Search>` components. How do you establish inheritance if these are not children of the `<Login>` component?

Comment: You have `Login` twice in your route config.. I think you should get rid of the outside one and keep `Login` as a child of `App`. That way you can easily pass values up to App via function, and then back down to your other routes using `cloneElement`. Either that or use redux

Comment: @azium: I added more context to my question, integrating some of the guidance you've provided. However, it's still not setting username in `<App>` and not sure how it would then pass to `<Feed>` and `<Search>` where the username would be necessary for making API calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's follow this chronologically from loading the app to signing in to displaying a user name in another component.

One thing before we start -- all app state will be in App. All other components will only receive values passed down as props (App state & functions).

**1) Someone visits your site at the root path `/`:**

- Your route config says load `<App />` and match `<Login />` to populate `this.props.children`
- `<App />` loads, sets the initial state of `{ username: '' }`
- App's `render` gets called, cloning its children (`Login`) and passing along `username` and `updateUser` as props. I would make minor modifications here:

  ```
  render() {
    // Children helper here because React children can be object or array
    var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        username: this.state.username,
        updateUser: this.updateUser // use same fn name for clarity 
      })
    })

    // give your root component some context / selection
    return <div id="app">{ children }</div>
  }
  ```

**2) User submits login form**

- Now that everything is going to be managed in `<App />` we can pare down `Login` to be a function rather than a React Component. (I'm going to remove some  for this example)

  ```
  var selectEl    

  var Login = function (props) {
    return (
      <form 
        className="loginForm" 
        onSubmit={function (event) { 
          event.preventDefault() // prevent page reloading
          props.updateUser(selectEl.value) 
        }} 
      >
        <select 
          defaultValue="user1" 
          ref={ function (node) { selectEl = node } }
        >
          <option value="user1">User 1</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
  ```

Few things to note here:

- This is just a function, so it has no initial state or lifecycle functions
- an empty variable is declared at the top.. when the `ref` callback function on your select element is called, the node will be stored in this variable
- `defaultValue` is used for your select (instead of just `value`), as you need this to get new values when switch options
- to pass arguments to `onSubmit` you need to declare a callback function. You can't just write `updateUser(value)` because `onSubmit` needs to be a function (not the return value of a function)

Now when you submit your form, the value of your select will go up to your `App`'s `updateUser` function. You probably want to do some redirect here, so I would augment your `updateUser` function to take a url, if it exists then redirect.

```
 updateUser: function(name, url) {
   this.setState({username: name})
   if (url) this.context.router.push(url)
 },
```

This should be everything you need.. then inside your other components, `this.props.username` will be populated:

```
var Feed = function (props) {
  return <div>{ props.username }</div>
}
```

Comment: spectacular answer. Having trouble with `this.context.router.push()` (getting an undefined error on `this.context` despite defining the contextType but I'll figure it out.

Comment: to clarify: every "component" is really not a <Component> but a function? I'm wondering how to invoke all of the other Components now, and how much restructuring I have to do (Feed is 254 lines long, for example, as a Component).

Comment: Not sure which version of react-router you're using but you can use `browserHistory.push` to avoid needing to add context (in 2.0x). Re: components, there are two ways of writing React 'components'. 1) calling React.createClass and 2) just the `render` function. Both ways are valid, but components which are simply render functions are easier to reason about. It helps push state and business logic up your component tree which is great. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so. `browserHistory.push` doesn't seem to work but I suspect there is a lot of refactoring I need to do. If you offer consultation via Codementor.io and are available this evening, please let me know. :)

Comment: The application process for codementor takes some time... feel free to email me and I'll invite you to my slack channel. djazium at gmail